# ReferenceError: logInModule is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

hi can someone help me with my code? it says the loginModule is not defined. can someone explain this to me. why can't define the function when i already call out on my html file? 
and nothing reflects to the console but error.

pardon me because i'm a new learner of JavaScript. hope you help me thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <!--[if IE]>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <![endif]-->
    <title>Support Admin</title>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP CORE STYLE CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- FONT AWESOME CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- CUSTOM STYLE CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nova+Flat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" type="text/css"> -->



    <script scr="support-admin\assets\data\admin-data.js"></script>
    <script src="support-admin\assets\js\index-admin.js"></script>






    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="head">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <a href="index.html">
                     <img src="assets/img/corelogo.png"  class="header-mid" />
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center" >

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <h4><span>Call:</span> +639351957952</h4>
                    <h4><span>E-mail:</span> michaelpelagio9830@gmail.com</h4>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">



                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">

                  <h3>Admin Login </h3>
                  <form>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <input id="userName" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Username / Email" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <input id="passWord" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Your Password" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <i class="btn btn-success" onClick="logInModule()">Click To Login</button>
                      </div>
                      <a href="#">Forgot Password ?</a>

                  </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </section>


    <!--  Jquery Core Script -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <!--  Core Bootstrap Script -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

then this is my javascript index-admin.js

```html
const logInModule = ()=>{
  var username = document.getElementById('userName');
  var password = document.getElementById('passWord');



    console.log(username);
    console.log(password);

}
```

whenever i click the button there's an error in console of my browser it says.

```html
index-admin.html:80 Uncaught ReferenceError: logInModule is not defined
    at HTMLElement.onclick (index-admin.html:80)
onclick @ index-admin.html:80
```

Comment: make sure `<script src="support-admin\assets\js\index-admin.js"></script>` is including your javascript file correctly , open page source , click on link , see if you will be redirected to your JS file

Comment: Try to add script file index-admin.js to bottom of html, just before jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: i try your suggestion guys but still nothing happen.